# Disable the post save process completely

Tags: admin, save-post

I need a way to disable the save process completely using an `action/filter`. Something that works (for e.g.:) in the `query`, `posts_clauses` or `wp_insert_post/save_post/update_post` hooks.

So far I only tried to `return '';`, which gives me tons of errors for missing values for post object parts in the admin UI.

This should happen "silently", so no errors get thrown when `php_error/WP_DEBUG` and such are set to `TRUE/On`.

Btw: I'm *not* asking for how to disable the autosave feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function disable_save( $maybe_empty, $postarr ) {
    $maybe_empty = true;

    return $maybe_empty;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_empty_content', 'disable_save', 999999, 2 );
```

Because `wp_insert_post_empty_content` is set to true, WordPress thinks there is no title and no content and stops updating the post.

**EDIT:** An even shorter variant would be:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_empty_content', '__return_true', PHP_INT_MAX -1, 2 );
```

Comment: Or `add_filter('wp_insert_post_empty_content', '__return_true');`

Comment: I guess you haven't tried this? The problem is that I get tons of `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$post_XY in R:\development\xampp\htdocs\wprepo\wp-admin\edit-form-advanced.php on line XY` and `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at R:\development\xampp\htdocs\wprepo\wp-admin\post-new.php:46) in R:\development\xampp\htdocs\wprepo\wp-includes\functions.php on line 86X`. It's exactly the same result as intercepting the `query` filter and returning `''/false/null`.

Comment: Ok, here's why **I** am wrong: I checked the 2nd argument inside the filter (see edit of your answer). There I checked if the `post_status` is `draft/pending/auto-draft`. The last one is a _real_ problem maker, as on every page-new re-load an auto-draft gets added to the database (which will be cleaned up by wp automagically). If I disable the save process there, then the above mentioned errors jump in. @ChristopherDavis I don't really understand why it works without priority and argument number in your case.

Comment: @kaiser Use of the `wp_insert_post_empty_content` filter is indeed problematic with auto-draft(s) and thus should be used with caution on knowledge of the caveat as explained in my answer.

Comment: @kaiser I'm curious about the use of `PHP_INT_MAX -1` instead of `PHP_INT_MAX`. Would you please explain that?

Comment: @DaveRomsey That's just to not completely lock out everyone who has to deal with that, but make sure it runs as "one of the last" commands in that chain. :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get notices for stopping inserts with the `wp_insert_post_empty_content` filter as mentioned in your comment at the https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51980/31794 answer, is that: For `post-new.php` the auto-draft process needs to get a `$post->ID` through `get_default_post_to_edit()` and `wp_insert_post()`, and use that ID from the $post return.
i.e. The 'Add New Post' pages actually creates and gets a new 'post record' every time.

Sadly wp_insert_post() return 0 if you stop the save process instead of an expected post ID. In other words, you can't stop 'Auto drafts' with the 'wp_insert_post_empty_content' filter. And should you use the filter, you sadly must let "auto-drafts pass through to avoid the PHP Notice. It's a pretty bad bug.

The only way I have found left to stop creating new auto-draft records pointlessly and go around this bug is, to extend the wpdb class with a db.php Drop-in plugin:

```
class wpdb_ext extends wpdb
{
  function insert($table, $data, $format = null) {
    if (isset($data['post_status']) && $data['post_status'] === "auto-draft" && ($pa = (int)$data['post_author'])
        && ($id = $this->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $table WHERE post_status = 'auto-draft' AND post_author = $pa LIMIT 1"))){
        //fake insert id and return id of existing auto-draft as base for New post page.
        return $this->insert_id = (int)$id;
    }
    return parent::insert($table, $data, $format = null);//else do actual insert
  }
}
$wpdb = new wpdb_ext(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);//overload wpdb
```

This keeps only one auto-draft per author, and avoids pointless new auto-draft(s) records wasting/skipping id increments for nothing.

Comment: Link to wordpress bug report for reference: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/27683

Comment: Be aware this will break plugin which rely on distinct IDs. Multilingual Press for example allows translations right from the _post new_ screen, it needs a new, unique ID to do that. Auto-drafts are deleted after a while, so there is no harm creating them.

Comment: @toscho What I am putting here does not prevent the return of a 'correct' ID. There is strictly no need to constantly create blank records is they can't be reused. That's an anti-pattern AFAIC. The Auto-drafts records are completely blank. Why would you need a new blank record every time when you already have one available? I'll look into Multilingual Press though.